# How to extract a string from email in zapier?

Tags: regex, zapier

I have a lead form that fetches name, phone and email address. This information is sent to a gmail id. I have set up zapier to extract this information and populate a google sheet.

The problem now here is that i am able to extract the email and phone number using zapiers extract name and phone number feature but i am not able to extract the name and populate it to the Google sheet.

The problem which i see is that all the data comes into body plain of the email and i cant figure how to separate the name and populate it to the Google sheet. Here is how it looks on zapier

https://ibb.co/hC9Qvdg

I belive it can be done through regex or something but i am a total noob. Can anyone help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: `^.+?(?=@.*$)` will give you everything before the first `@`.

Comment: But that will give the complete message before the first @. Is there anyway I can use regex to fetch everything before the first #.                                                                          I can put a * or # in front of the name field. So it would look something like this.                                                               Name : test#. The regex can then take the # and fetch everything before the #.    Is it possible?

Comment: tried it but it didn't return anything

Comment: Do you have created a code run block, or how are you doing it? And can you please add a raw sample of your email body that contains the text to extract, please? E.g. https://regex101.com/r/kHbOO9/1

Answer (score 0):

Pretty difficult to guess what problem you might be facing, yet an expression that'd look like the following might be maybe OK to look into:

```
Name\s*:\s*([^\r\n]*)|Email\s*:\s*(\S+@\S+\.\S+)|Phone\s*:\s*([^\r\n]+)
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BAOfC9/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/BAOfC9/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]